# wxWidgets library build garbled file name in linker

Tags: wxwidgets

On attempting to build wxWidgets 3.1.0 libraries, I am getting this error

```
ar: gcc_mswu\moolib_fontmap.o: No such file or directory
```

A file does exists with a slightly different spelling

```
 Directory of C:\Users\James\code\wxwidgets-3.1.0\build\msw\gcc_mswu

2017-01-05  02:01 PM            98,886 monolib_fontmap.o
```

It looks like a typo in the makefile, or like a letter is missed reading the makefile.  Is that possible?

Except: if I redirect the console output to a file and open in an editor , the correct spelling shows up:

[image]

So the correct command is going to the linker, but the linker is looking for a garbled filename!

Here is the complete recipe for what I am doing:

```
Download wxWidgets source code from https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/releases/download/v3.1.0/wxWidgets-3.1.0.7z

Unpack to a folder. On my system, I use C:\Users\James\code\wxwidgets-3.1.0

Open a command window.

cd to the code::blocks mingw folder. On my system this is C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks16\MinGW

Type mingwvars.bat

cd to wxwidgets folder. On my system C:\Users\James\code\wxwidgets-3.1.0

cd to ./build/msw

Type mingw32-make SHELL=CMD.exe -j4 -f makefile.gcc BUILD=release UNICODE=1 SHARED=0 MONOLITHIC=1
```

Comment: Unfortunately the red line is covering the file name. Can you re-make the screenshot?

Comment: @Igor look just above the redline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be the same problem as the one mentioned [in the wiki](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_wxWidgets_with_MinGW#To_fix_the_issue_.22The_input_line_is_too_long.22_when_compile_static_library_with_MONOLITHIC_option). Apparently there is a bug in mingw32-make with very long command lines which makes it (sometimes?) eat characters in them...

Yes.  Applying the recipe in the link you posted fixed the problem.  Here are the details:

modify makefile.gcc as following:

From:

```
ifeq ($(MONOLITHIC),1)
ifeq ($(SHARED),0)
$(LIBDIRNAME)\libwx$(PORTNAME)$(WXUNIVNAME)$(WX_RELEASE_NODOT)$(WXUNICODEFLAG)$(WXDEBUGFLAG)$(WX_LIB_FLAVOUR).a: $(MONOLIB_OBJECTS)
    if exist $@ del $@
    ar rcu $@ $(MONOLIB_OBJECTS)
    ranlib $@
endif
endif
```

Replace second occurence of $(MONOLIB_OBJECTS) with gcc_mswu\monolib*.o:

```
ifeq ($(MONOLITHIC),1)
ifeq ($(SHARED),0)
$(LIBDIRNAME)\libwx$(PORTNAME)$(WXUNIVNAME)$(WX_RELEASE_NODOT)$(WXUNICODEFLAG)$(WXDEBUGFLAG)$(WX_LIB_FLAVOUR).a: $(MONOLIB_OBJECTS)
    if exist $@ del $@
    ar rcu $@ gcc_mswu\\monolib*.o
    ranlib $@
endif
endif
```

Comment: I have added details to your link only answer.  Why was this change not made to the wxwidgets master?  Would have saved me several hours!

Comment: These makefiles are generated by a tool that can't generate the wildcards on its own. Also, using wildcards is arguably wrong, we have the full list of files we want to link and we should be able to just use them -- if not for this bug...

Comment: How about updating the wiki so that this fix can be more easily found?  Instead of "To fix the issue "The input line is too long"" have "To fix the issue "No such file or directory""

Comment: Sure, please do it.