# CodeBlocks: How to build C++ App w using wxWidgets library DLLs

Tags: c++, codeblocks, wxwidgets

I have downloaded and installed binaries of wxWidgets and Codeblocks onto my PC with Windows 10. Codeblocks builds and runs HelloWorld. With Codeblocks I then open an existing DEV-C++ project which uses wxWidgets - Codeblocks compiles this with no problems, but the linker fails with a message that a library dll file of Widgets is an "unrecognized format".
have spent several hours looking for help on this forum and on the widgets site. I have read about Export Libraries which bridge the gap between the calls in the App and the functions in the shared DLLs, but have failed to find them. What is the correct way to link to the Widgets library? Thank you for any help you can give me.

Comment: I would suggest building the wxWidgets libraries with code:blocks from source, rather than downloading a binary library that was built with an unknown compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest building the wxWidgets libraries with code:blocks from source, rather than downloading a binary library that was built with an unknown compiler

Here are instructions to build the wxWidgets static libraries with code:block.  Ti build DLLs, modify step 8.  ( Note that your applications will start faster if you use the static library.

Download wxWidgets source code from https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/releases/download/v3.1.0/wxWidgets-3.1.0.7z

Unpack to a folder. On my system, I use C:\Users\James\code\wxwidgets-3.1.0

Open a command window.

cd to the code::blocks mingw folder. On my system this is C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks16\MinGW

Type mingwvars.bat

cd to wxwidgets folder. On my system C:\Users\James\code\wxwidgets-3.1.0

cd to ./build/msw

Type `mingw32-make SHELL=CMD.exe -j4 -f makefile.gcc BUILD=release UNICODE=1 SHARED=0 MONOLITHIC=1` If you get strange 'file not found' errors you will need to edit the makefile - details are here http://stackoverflow.com/a/41498057/16582

Set code::blocks global variable wxwidgets as follows:

```
base                      C:\Users\James\code\wxWidgets-3.1.0
include                   C:\Users\James\code\wxWidgets-3.1.0\include
lib                       C:\Users\James\code\wxwidgets-3.1.0\lib\gcc_lib
setup ( user-defined )    C:\Users\James\code\wxWidgets-3.1.0\lib\gcc_lib\mswu
```

Comment: Thank you ravenspoint for your suggestion. The Widgets dlls I downloaded worked fine under DEV-C++ so I dont think the problem lies there. Can you tell me whether CodeBlocks IDE can build Windows Apps which link dynamically to dll libraries?

Comment: "Can you tell me whether CodeBlocks IDE can build Windows Apps which link dynamically to dll libraries?"     Yes.

Comment: Again, thank you ravenspoint. Please help me to get CB to to it for me too! The Add Library dialog of the Linker tab in the Compiler Settings dialogs (both global and project) doesn't offer .dll as an option and if you force ddls into the list then, when trying to link, you get that same "unrecognized format" error. The help info sheds no light.

Comment: Maybe I mentioned this before?  You have to build the library using code:blocks.