# wxwidgets platform.h error: no such file or directory wx/setup.h

Tags: codeblocks, wxwidgets

I am using Code::Blocks with wxwidgets and I have `include` and `lib` folders under Document\wxwidgets. I am very new to c++ libraries. In Code::Blocks project initialization, I entered the location for wxwidgets. Then in setting/global enviornment variables I entered in `base` the Document\wxwidgets again. Still, I am not able to run the app. It shows the error in the `include/wx/platform.h` file where it says

> C:\Users\Programming coder\Documents\wxwidgets\include\wx\platform.h|148|fatal error: wx/setup.h: No such file or directory|

I am not able to solve this and would appreciate some help. Also I checked and the `wx` folder does not seem to be there in the location. I don't know if that is normal.

Also, I downloaded the headers(`include`) from the wxwidgets github repo download page, `wxWidgets-3.1.1-headers.7z`. Any help appreciated.

Also, I am aware some questions exist already, but their problems are in different because most are using linux. Also I am using Code::Blocks IDE.

Comment: Instructions for building wxWidgets using code::blocks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47115536/16582

Comment: For developing applications with wxWidgets you need to download the compiler-independent wxWidgets-3.1.1_Headers.7z file and one of wxMSW-3.1.1-vcXXX_Dev.7z or wxMSW-3.1.1_gccXXX_Dev.7z files depending on your compiler, its version and the target architecture (x86 if not specified or x64).
Unpack both files into the same directory so that include and lib directories are at the same level after unpacking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build wxWidgets itself before building the applications using it. Its build process will create the `setup.h` file which is currently missing.

Note that, in principle, you could also use precompiled binaries, but in this case you must use exactly the same compiler as was used for compiling them, i.e. TDM gcc.

Comment: I used the precompiled tdm-gcc binary when doing this.

Comment: Then you just need to set the include paths correctly, i.e. add `lib/gcc_dll/mswu` directory to them.